# returning certain sum values of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.4

Basically this is a combination program. It sums up all values in dict1 and returns all key combinations that add to 100. I want to get the same result, but I don't want certain key/values to be in the same combination group. ie I don't want key 'a' to be in any combination group with key 'b', key 'c' not be in any combination group with 'd', etc.

```
import itertools
dict1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4, 'e':5, 'f':6, 'g':7, 'f':8}

def matches(d, target):
    # First try single items, then couples, then triplets etc.
    for num in range(1,len(d)+1):
        # Iterate over all possible combinations of length num
        for com in itertools.combinations(d.items(), num):
            # Does the sum of all second items per key/value pair match the target?
            if sum(item[1] for item in com) == target:
                # Yield one item at a time, so the caller can decide when to stop

                yield dict(com).keys()

for match in matches(dict1, 100):
    print(match)
```

Comment: Does your code work? What is it doing that it shouldn't? What isn't it doing that it should?  What is your question, please be specific?  Please include the desired and actual output for the example input.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is, that the logic of the program doesn't work in this form.

The maximum of `sum(item[1] for item in com)` is `30`, then the loops end. Thus function `matches` doesn't `yield` anything.